# Laravel Schema onDelete set default

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, foreign-keys

I have two tables with a one-to-one relationship, set by a foreign key constraint. I want to set the `onDelete` rule to 'set default', meaning that when a row on the foreign table is dropped, the reference value reverts to its default value. Here is my code:

Tours Table:

```
Schema::create('tours', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->integer('grade')->unsigned()->default(1);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Grades Table:

```
Schema::create('grades', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Set Foreign Key:

```
Schema::table('tours', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('grade')->references('id')->on('grades')->onDelete('set default');
});
```

When I run my migrations, it works- no errors. However, looking at the table in HeidiSQL, it hasn't worked properly; the foreign key has been set, but the onDelete property just shows 'NO ACTION'.

Subsequently when I delete a row in the grades table, I get a foreign key constraint error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it should be as `->onDelete('cascade')`.

Comment: No, that means that the child row will be deleted. I don't want it to be deleted- I want the value to revert to its default which I have specified in the creation schema which you can see above. This should be possible; please see: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2365/sql-server-foreign-key-update-and-delete-rules/

Comment: I have the same problem now. Have you fixed it? @Inigo

Comment: @Jed Sorry my friend, I never did get to the bottom of this. I think in this case I just wrote a script to manually fill in the default value when the row was deleted. Seems like maybe a bug, I'm surprised there hasn't been more talk about this. Feel free to start a bounty... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while but.. it depends on the engine your database uses. If you use [InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-storage-engine.html) or [NDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-cluster.html), **the syntax will be parsed but ignored**.

Check [this section](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-referential-actions) of the MySQL documentation:

> #### Referential Actions
>
> ...
>
> `SET DEFAULT`: This action is recognized by the MySQL parser, but both [InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-storage-engine.html) and [NDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-cluster.html) **reject** table definitions containing `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT` or `ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT` clauses.

You could use `SET NULL` instead in case this suit your needs. If not, then you could create an [observer](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#observers) that'd perform this operation for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution.

First set the foreign key reference without any constraints.

Here is the code from the migration:
`$table->foreignId('category_id');`

Then set deleting model event on that model and update each related model:
Here I am updating `category_id` to `1` which is the default category and named as uncategorized and this can not be deleted.
`Category::deleting(function ($category) {`
 `$recipe_ids = $category->recipes->pluck('id');`
 `Recipe::whereIn('id', $recipe_ids)->update(['category_id' => 1]);`
`});`

Answer (score 0):

I just came here looking for the same answer, I checked the documentation at the same time to find any way to directly manage the deletion of the foreign key, and setting a default value.
Unfortunately I couldn't find a direct method to do it, but to the best of my knowledge, there is a way to do it with the help of model observers.
The way I believe it could work (though it's somewhat tedious, and does the job with 2 queries instead of 1, which is a bit inefficient), is basically where

1. You will have to make the foreign key attribute nullable

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger("grade")->nullable();
```

2. You can set the on delete function to set the value to null, instead of cascading

```
$table->foreign("grade")->references("id")->on("grades")->onDelete("set null");
```

3. On the model for the given migration you will have to set an observer

```
public static function boot() {
    parent::boot();
    self::updating(function(Tour $tour) {
        if($tour->isDirty('grade')) {
            $tour->grade = [DEFAULT VALUE HERE];
        }
    });
}
```

This should be able to set the value to a default value on the deletion of your grade.

NOTE: This isn't the most efficient way, and I can't confirm whether this is the only way to do it, this is the way I think it can work, and I have used, and it's the best way I know how to do it
I still am a novice programmer, if there is a better way to do it, please feel free to mention me.